# Java applet: Java.exe process exits after about 1 minute, next generation java plugin

Tags: java, applet, jvm, next-generation-plugin

Circumstances:
- Windows 7
- JRE 1.7_51
- IE9
- Printing applet (10 JARs, signed (not selfsigned), manifest set)

I'm comparing the Enable next-generation Java plugin check on and off setting on JRE 1.7_51. My problem is that with the plugin enabled JVM (java.exe) that is running the applet exits automatically after about 1 minute. Since I use about 9 libraries in my applet and they are all signed correctly, JVM start takes about 30 seconds (which is too long for me). 
With the plugin disabled JVM is embeded in the iexplorer.exe process and never exits. The first load of the applet takes about 10 seconds, after that the applet is already loaded in JVM and it starts right away (1 second).

I can see the behaviour of both processess in Windows task manager.

I want to achieve the same applet load result with the plugin enabled. Is there a way to do that?
I researched the issue and I'm afraid it might be a Java by design thing.

Thank you!

Comment: Enable tracing and loggin in java control panel (Debugging). Then please post any messages here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying but the trace was too long ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using the Java Panel to enable/disable to the next generation plugin, you can add a special tag in the first applet to keep the JVM loaded for the next one.

```
<PARAM NAME="legacy_lifecycle" VALUE="true">
```

Comment: Awesome. I can't believe it works and that I could not find this before. Thanks a million!